# Where can i find royalty free game assets for Xna

Tags: xna, sprite, textures, texture2d, xnanimation

I am currently thinking of starting to use xna to create some free games to practice my programming using the framework. I am looking for some free game art and sound-effects to use in my project. It will also help me generate ideas. Its really just to go over concepts and make a basic game with some relatively good textures and sound-effects. I saw some on the internet, but is there like a review of the best ones or any that i can find because the copyright on some of the sites i visited seem to be very indecisive in their meaning. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is probably not the right place to ask this question. This site is more related to programming than finding game assets. Good luck!

Comment: This question belongs on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but whilst you're there, here's one question that will certainly interest you: [http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images).

Comment: Ooh i do apologise, i will ask future art and general gaming related questions there, and thanks for the reply everyone. Keep the coding questions here, got it.

Comment: Ooh and thanks john for the link that had a lot of useful info and content.

Comment: @JohnH - that is an excellent thread you linked to.

Comment: @ananthonline / Dan: Glad you found it useful.  It helped me out a while back. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a couple of websites there on the internet really, for my projects when i was looking for place holders, instead of looking for free art i looked for a list of websites because a lot of the websites don't contain great art although some have some little gold nuggets of art. You should check out some of these websites that cover free art.

Free textures and sound-effects at [learning c#](http://learningcsharp.co.uk/free-game-content/) and the same is available at [funplosion](http://www.funplosion.com/free-assets.html). The licensing and relevant websites are covered in both. Hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, just checked out both, the copyright is better explained at least, just gotta look through to find what i need now.